# cypress error - cy.select() failed because this element is currently disabled

Tags: javascript, jquery, cypress

I am using Cypress.io testing platform and Chrome browser/latest version.

I have 3 Select dropdowns. The first one is enabled by default so I can select it no problem; the second and third are disabled. When making selections manually and the first dropdown is selected, the 2nd dropdown enables, then when the 2nd dropdown is selected, the 3rd one enables. I can address each one individually using `cy.get` by using their name, or by their index 0,1, or 2; so I will just use the index of each in this question.

Now when I programatically select the first dropdown by using Cypress:

`cy.get('select').eq(0).select('Nursing', {force: true})`

... the 2nd dropdown stays disabled. I added a `cy.wait(2000)` [2 seconds] after selecting the 1st dropdown, plenty of time to be selected, and then I try selecting the 2nd dropdown like this: `cy.get('select').eq(1).select('US - Alaska', {force: true})`, and I get this error:

`CypressError: Timed out retrying: cy.select() failed because this element is currently disabled: <select id="course-finder-location-select" name="course_finder_location" data-select2-id="course-finder-location-select" disabled="" tabindex="-1" class="select2-hidden-accessible" aria-hidden="true"></select>`, which is the 2nd select.

As you can see, I used its index via `eq(1)` and it correctly identifies it as the 2nd select.

I am trying to figure out how to enable the 2nd dropdown using Cypress testing commands. I have even included a jQuery CDN which does not cause an error; but when I try adding a jQuery command which works in the console [it enables the 2nd select]:

`jQuery("#course-finder-location-select").prop( "disabled", false )`,

my Cypress test simply crashes with no errors. It does not seem to like jQuery commands, or even JavaScript - I tried this, too:

`document.getElementById("course-finder-location-select").disabled = false`

[although I can get it to do a `window.alert("!")`].

Any ideas how to get the 2nd select to enable using Cypress? I am not able to alter the HTML file at all.

Thank you in advance for your time! If you have any suggestions how I can reword this, let me know. I do not have a sandbox for Cypress set up yet.

Answer (score 0):

Use this for 2nd drop-down:

```
cy.get('select').eq(1).should('contains','US - Alaska')
```